# How to evaluate the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\frac{1}{n} - \frac{2}{n} + \frac{3}{n} - ... + \frac{(-1)^{n-1}n}{n}|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> How to evaluate the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\frac{1}{n} - \frac{2}{n} + \frac{3}{n} - ... + \frac{(-1)^{n-1}n}{n}|$?

I reckon this limit should be a half, given that for each even member of the sequence of partial sums we get a half of n and the whole sequence is then divided by n.

First member ($n = 1$): $\frac{1}{n}|1| = 1 $,

Second member ($n = 2, n $ is odd): $\frac{1}{2}|1-2| = \frac{1}{2}$

Third member ($n = 3$): $\frac{1}{3}|1-2+3| = \frac{2}{3}$

Fourth member ($n = 4, n$ is odd): $\frac{1}{4}|1-2+3-4| = \frac{1}{2}$;

again, the result being even, same with further even members if you go on like this.

I've tried writing it as a sum of the odd members, and then subtract the even members, however, the index at which I should stop is not really clear to me, since, if n is odd, I end up at a non-integer index if I try to put in a half of n (to get +n to be the last member).

That being said, I did find a solution which first sums all the members as positives and then subtracts all the even members multiplied by two like so:

$1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n - 2(2 + 4 + ... + n)$

However, again, this approach HAS to include an assumption about $n$ being even or odd (in the above case I found, the assumption is it's even), so it's not really clear to me whether this is really valid, since we don't know whether to include $n$ among the even members.

Comment: Can't you show that the difference between an odd sum and the preceding even sum goes to zero?

Comment: When $n = 2k$ is even, we have $$\frac{1}{2k}|(1-2)+(2-3)+\cdots+((2k-1)-2k)| = \frac{1}{2k}|-k| = \frac{1}{2},$$ and when $n = 2k+1$ is odd, we have $$\frac{1}{2k+1}|(1-2)+(2-3)+\cdots+((2k-1)-2k)+(2k+1)| = \frac{1}{2k+1}|k+1| = \frac{1+1/k}{2}.$$ In total the sequence approaches to $1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

One can show the following slightly more general formula (for $x\ne 1$) for a sum related to the one inside the modulus in the question:
$$
\sum_{0\le k\le n}kx^k
=
\frac x{(x-1)^2}\Big(nx^{n + 1} - (n+1)x^n  + 1\Big)\ .
\tag{$1$}
$$
This relation is clear for $n=0$ (including the case $x=0$ as a limit case), and for the induction step from $(n-1)$ to $n$ we need the identity:
$$
\frac x{(x-1)^2}\Big((n-1)x^n - nx^{n - 1}  + 1\Big)
+ nx^n
=
\frac x{(x-1)^2}\Big(nx^{n + 1} - (n+1)x^n  + 1\Big)\ .
$$
After cancelling the $+1$ term on both sides inside the parentheses, multiplying with $(x-1)^2$, and dividing by $x^n$, we obtain equivalently:
$$
\Big((n-1)x - n  \Big)
+ n(x-1)^2
=
\Big(nx^2 - (n+1)x\Big)
\ ,
$$
which is true.

---

Now let us plug in $x=-1$ in the relation $(1)$, and let us take the modulus. We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac 1n\left|\sum_{0\le k\le n}k(-1)^k\right|
&=
\frac 1n\cdot
\left|\frac {(-1)}{(-2)^2}\Big(-n(-1)^n - (n+1)(-1)^n  + 1\Big)\right|
\\
&=
\frac 1{4n}\cdot
\Big[\ (2n+1)-(-1)^n\ \Big]
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This is an explicit formula for the general term, it delivers for instance for $n=1$ the value $\frac 14(3-(-1))=1$, for $n=2$ the value $\frac 18(5+1)=\frac 68=\frac 34$, for $n=3$ the value $\frac 1{12}(7-(-1))=\frac 8{12}=\frac 23$, and so on. Writing this expression with a forced division by $n$ as
$$
\frac 14\cdot
\left[\ \left(2+\frac 1n\right)-\frac{(-1)^n}n\ \right]\ ,
$$
we see that the limit is $\frac 14[(2+0)-0]=\frac 12$.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the subsequence for odd $n$ and compute the limit and the even $n$ and compute the limit. It will turn aout that both converge to $\frac{1}{2}$. It is a lemma from Analysis 1 that then the whole sequence converges to $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar answer in the comments. In my answer the comparison between odd and even n is done directly. No other difference otherwise.

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^n{(-1)^{i-1}}=\left\{ \begin{align}&-\frac{n}{2},&\text{n even}\\ &-\frac{n}{2}+n+1,&\text{n odd}\end{align}\right.$$

$$-\frac{n}{2}\le S\le \frac{n}{2}+1$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\le \left |\frac{S}{n}\right |\le \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\left |\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{n}}\right |}=\frac{1}{2}$$